# Matching columns in two files

Tags: files

I have two files. Some of the names in file1 are also in file2.
How to assign the column $3 a $4 of the second file to the first one following the match between $3 of the first file and $2 of the second file? Thank you very much.

```
file1.dat

1 2.5   S1    2.5
1 54    S2    2.5
2 465   S3    1.4
2 65    D     4.2
3 465   P     4.2
3 897   L     4.2
4 12    H_L   4.2
4 46    H_M   4.2

file2.dat

1 S1    2.55    4
2 S2    2.56    6
3 S3    1.44    8
4 D     4.22    7
5 H_L   4.2     6
6 H_M   4.2     65
```

desired output:

```
1 2.5   S1    2.5   2.55    4
1 54    S2    2.5   2.56    6
2 465   S3    1.4   1.44    8
2 65    D     4.2   4.22    7
3 465   P     4.2   -       -
3 897   L     4.2   -       -
4 12    H_L   4.2   4.2     6
4 46    H_M   4.2   4.2     65
```

Answer (score 3):

This problem has been solved umpteen times in here. How about

```
awk 'NR==FNR {Tmp[$2] = $3 FS $4; next} ($3 in Tmp) {print $0 FS Tmp[$3]}' file2 file1
1 2.5   S1    2.5 2.55 4
1 54    S2    2.5 2.56 6
2 465   S3    1.4 1.44 8
2 65    D     4.2 4.22 7
4 12    H_L   4.2 4.2 6
4 46    H_M   4.2 4.2 65
```

Read the desired fields of file2 into an array indexed by `$2`, and then, if `$3` of file1 matches an index in the array, append the resp. element to `$0`, and print.

For the two NOT matching lines try e.g.

```
awk 'NR==FNR {Tmp[$2] = $3 FS $4; next} ($3 in Tmp) {print $0 FS Tmp[$3]; next} {print $0, "- -"}' file2 file1
1 2.5   S1    2.5 2.55 4
1 54    S2    2.5 2.56 6
2 465   S3    1.4 1.44 8
2 65    D     4.2 4.22 7
3 465   P     4.2 - -
3 897   L     4.2 - -
4 12    H_L   4.2 4.2 6
4 46    H_M   4.2 4.2 65
```

Comment: Thank you and how to add also not matching lines completed by '-' on the corresponding places, please?